# IntelliJ IDEA: Is there a way to set a default timestamp format for a oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, intellij-idea, timestamp, plsqldeveloper

I have created a table that has a column with the "timestamp (6)" data type.

In PLSQL Developer, I can Insert and get the query result with this timestamp format: `'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SSXFF AM'`, but I can't do the same in IntelliJ IDEA.

IntelliJ IDEA only gets new entries in this format: `"DD-MM-RR HH:MI:SSXFF"` and shows the existing ones in that format as well.

for example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_time (reg_id NUMBER, reg_time TIMESTAMP) ;
INSERT INTO test_time VALUES(1, '01-JAN-2003 2:00:00 AM');
commit;
```

I can insert a value like this `27-FEB-23 01:00:00.000000 PM` into the reg_time using PLSQL Developer but I can't enter the same value using intellij idea, it gives this error `ORA-01843: not a valid month`, to solve the problem, I have to change the format to this `2023-02-27 13:00:00.000000`.

I was wondering if there is a way that I can set a default timestamp format for this type of field in IntelliJ IDEA?

P.S I've altered the value during a session using this command, but it didn't work and I still get the ORA-01843:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SSXFF AM';
```

Comment: Define "didn't work".  Was there an error?  If so, what error?  Did your actual command have 2 underscores between `TIMESTAMP` and `TZ` as in your question?  Or is that a typo in posting the question?

Comment: That also isn't the right setting - this is a timestamp, not a timestamp with time zone, so `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SSXFF AM';` without the `_TZ` (or `__TZ` *8-). But in general you shouldn't be relying on default formatting. Are you passing the value (in set and get) as a string, rather than a native timestamp object?

Comment: you were right, it was a typo, I updated my question.

Comment: Seems NLS is not supported yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-530/Support-nls-settings-for-oracle

Comment: That shouldn't affect setting them via `alter session` - it just means you have to do that yourself, it isn't built into IDEA itself (yet) doesn't it? (Though again, relying on NLS settings isn't generally a good idea anyway...) Actually, that issue seems to be for the DataGrip client, not IDEA?